# Automate the codeception Testing in yii2

Tags: php, testing, yii2, codeception

I wanted to automate the functional codeception testing in yii2,I am able to test the login  API using the following code

```
use tests\codeception\backend\FunctionalTester;
$I = new FunctionalTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('Check when authenticated');
$I->sendPOST('/login', ['password' => '11111111', 'email'=>'check@check.com']);
$I->seeResponseCodeIs(200);
$I->seeResponseIsJson();
$I->seeResponseContains('"result"');
$I->seeResponseContains('"message"');
$I->haveHttpHeader('Accept','application/json');
$I->seeResponseContains('"message":"OK"');
```

In Login API I return the auth_token which can be used for further processing,So Where do I save the result of login API and use it for testing the further API's

Comment: Store it in a static property of Page object http://codeception.com/docs/06-ReusingTestCode#PageObjects

Comment: that can used for testing the API's

Answer (score 1):

We can store the response using the following function.and check it further for API's

```
$check = $I->grabResponse();
$check = json_decode($check,true);
```